# Export Region definitions - GRASS GIS

Tags: grass-gis

I use two different Landsat datasets in different computers. But the region settings I work is the same. Is it possible to export the region settings in the form of a file in GRASS?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The region files reside within the `windows` folder of your mapset, and provided that the projection information is the same between the mapsets, can safely be copied. You can generate a saved region by typing `g.region save=test`, here's an example file:

```
proj:       99
zone:       0
north:      1724519.03591606
south:      -1658266.80294581
east:       2745189.73967152
west:       -3134521.46538088
cols:       7832
rows:       4506
e-w resol:  750.72921413
n-s resol:  750.72921413
top:        1
bottom:     0
cols3:      7832
rows3:      4506
depths:     1
e-w resol3: 750.72921413
n-s resol3: 750.72921413
t-b resol:  1
```

Comment: ... or you copy over the WIND file stored within the mapset.